# Is there a way to show partitions on Cloudera impala?

Tags: cloudera, impala

Normally, I can do `show partitions <table>` in hive. But when it is a parquet table, hive does not understand it. I can go to hdfs and check the dir structure, but that is not ideal. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 12):

I am using Impala 1.4.0 and I can see partitions.
From the impala-shell give the command:

```
show partitions <mytablename>
```

I have something looking like this:

```
 +-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+---------+--------------+---------+
| year  | month | day | #Rows | #Files | Size    | Bytes Cached | Format  |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+--------+---------+--------------+---------+
| 2013  | 11    | 1   | -1    | 3      | 25.87MB | NOT CACHED   | PARQUET |
| 2013  | 11    | 2   | -1    | 3      | 24.84MB | NOT CACHED   | PARQUET |
| 2013  | 11    | 3   | -1    | 2      | 19.05MB | NOT CACHED   | PARQUET |
| 2013  | 11    | 4   | -1    | 3      | 23.63MB | NOT CACHED   | PARQUET |
| 2013  | 11    | 5   | -1    | 3      | 26.56MB | NOT CACHED   | PARQUET |
```

Alternatively you can go to your table in HDFS . They are normally seen in this path:
`/user/hivestore/warehouse/<mytablename>` or

```
/user/hive/warehouse/<mytablename>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah impala added the support since then.

Comment: Checking via hdfs is not ideal also might not be accurate. The file could be write to hdfs but not recognized in impala.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. [Issue](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-334) is open though. So checking it manually seems to be the only option right now.